# Focusing in textarea (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script that copy to clipboard a value of textarea from time to time and I want to make that when the value was copied the texarea is automatically focus in. Now I must click to active this element so I must click every 5 seconds to write then.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  setInterval(function take() {
    let textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }, 5000)
})();
```

Comment: It should be `textArea.focus();`, not `textArea.select();`.

Comment: You should also move `let textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');` outside of the timer function so you don't have to keep searching for the same element you already searched for.

Comment: When i changed to the `textArea.focus();` the value of textArea wasn't copied to clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set the cursor at the end of the text in textarea by using `textArea.setSelectionRange(-1, -1);` after `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` though documentation says that this method does not focus the element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement.